# vs2015 warning C4018: '<=': signed/unsigned mismatch

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

This code throws a warnings when I compile it. Any solutions?

```
int inter_party_check_exp_share(struct party_data *const p)
{
    nullpo_ret(p);
    return (p->party.count < 2 || p->max_lv - p->min_lv <= party_share_level);
}
```

Comment: It would help if you include declarations of the variables used, if not a full, compilable example. I would speculate that one side of the comparison is unsigned and the other side is signed. This results in an automatic conversion of the signed value to unsigned with sometimes unwanted results.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you've declared min_lv to be an unsigned int, or party_share_level to be an unsigned int.  Either way, you are comparing a two ints that are mismatched in their signedness, which is what the error is telling you.  you can fix it with a statc_cast<(un)signed int>() on the correct variable, or just ignore the warning all together; it doesn't really mean much.